# Strange behaviour from joint_trajectory_action to ABB robot

Tags: ros, joint-trajectory-action, ros-industrial, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello friends,

I have a very strange problem with my ABB IRB 140.
When I use RViz to plan a motion, everything works as expected. So i tried to write a node, which uses moveit to control my IRB140. Everything works as expected through /joint_path_command (see picture).
Problem is: On the RobotStudio side I get very strange joint values. I.e.: If I send [0.0 , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4] from my script "simpleplanner", my robot recieves [0.0 , 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]. Somehow it clones the value from a joint to another joint/joints. This also happens when I directly write into the /joint_trajectory_action node, thus skipping moveit.
Since the values are correct up to /joint_path_command, I assume the problem lays in /motion_download_interface. Which is strange cause, everything works fine sending motions via Rviz.

Thanks in advance!
Regards - Timo

[image description http://www2.pic-upload.de/img/29714923/rqt_graph.png](http://www2.pic-upload.de/img/29714923/rqt_graph.png)
[image description http://www2.pic-upload.de/img/29714920/jointpathcommand.png](http://www2.pic-upload.de/img/29714920/jointpathcommand.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226402/strange-behaviour-from-joint_trajectory_action-to-abb-robot/) by [cobhc999](https://answers.ros.org/users/14666/cobhc999/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your screenshot doesn't show the situation you describe in your question text, but what you're seeing is most likely the effect of the joint2-joint3 joint coupling that some ABB robots have.

That coupling influences the joint position values reported by the RAPID runtime to the ROS driver (ie: the values don't actually correspond to the *real-world* angle of the joints), so the ROS driver has to compensate for that, if configured to do so. All launch files distributed through the [ros-industrial/abb](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb) and [ros-industrial/abb_experimental](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_experimental) repositories set the `J23_coupled` launch file argument ([here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_experimental/blob/58523e0693751fa5bc3c711324694ab565169800/abb_irb120_support/launch/robot_interface_download_irb120.launch#L12), for the IRB 120 fi), which gets passed on to the `abb_driver` nodes ([here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/blob/1c49136fcba61371e26f32a5c3e92870e1443519/abb_driver/src/abb_utils.cpp#L47-L53)). Finally, that value is used to calculate the corrected joint angles for `joint_3` ([here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/blob/1c49136fcba61371e26f32a5c3e92870e1443519/abb_driver/src/abb_utils.cpp#L47-L53)). Both `JointStates` ([here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/blob/1c49136fcba61371e26f32a5c3e92870e1443519/abb_driver/src/abb_robot_state_node.cpp#L52-L59)) and `JointTrajectoryPoint`s ([here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb/blob/1c49136fcba61371e26f32a5c3e92870e1443519/abb_driver/src/abb_joint_downloader_node.cpp#L59-L66)) undergo this compensation.

So in the case of your screenshot: `joint_3` (compensated) would be `joint_2 + joint_3`, or `0.092507.. + 0.328967.. ~= 0.421474..`.

Now whether this is correct for your IRB 140 depends on whether that robot has the same joint2-joint3 coupling. I've never worked with one, so I can't tell you. You'll have to (en|dis)able the `J23_coupled` parameter and see what the effect is on your simulated robot. Easiest is just to start the `robot_state_visualize_...launch` file and jog the robot in RobotStudio: RViz should show the exact same robot poses. You will very quickly recognise an incorrect setting for `J23_coupled`.

The fact that MoveIt trajectory execution already ''works just fine' seems to suggest that the value you currently use is correct though. But it's always good to make sure.

---

PS: if you are interested, you could install the [packet-simplemessage](https://github.com/ros-industrial/packet-simplemessage) Wireshark dissector, which will show you the `JointTrajectoryPoint` messages actually send by `abb_driver` (and received by your controller/simulator). Look for `JOINT_TRAJ_PT` and `JOINT_POSITION` messages. They should show the non-compensated angles.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cobhc999](https://answers.ros.org/users/14666/cobhc999/) on 2016-02-12**:
Thank you very much! If I had asked earlier, this would have saved me a whole workday of debugging!
If have seen the J23_coupled parameter before. Since the IRB2400 (which packets I modified for my IRB140) has similiar kinematics like the IRB140, I thought I could leave this parameter as it is.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-12**:
If both state visalisation and trajectory execution are ok with the value you have right now, then yes, you can leave it as it is.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-12**:
Would you be interested to contribute your IRB 140 package(s) back to the `abb_experimental` repository? That would be very much appreciated. There might be some (minor) work involved to make sure things conform to ROS-I conventions, but that is something we can iterate on.

**Comment by [cobhc999](https://answers.ros.org/users/14666/cobhc999/) on 2016-02-12**:
Of course! I would be glad to return something to the community. But since I'm an amateur in ROS you would totally have to check the packages. Maybe its usable. How should I provide the packages?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-12**:
The easiest is probably to make a *fork* of the `abb_experimental` repository on github, add your new `abb_irb140_support` (and any other related pkgs) to it (in a new branch) and then submit a PR back to `abb_experimental`. The maintainers will review your PR and merge it if it is ok.